# Solving non-linear coupled differential equations in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, simulation

I am working on simulation of a system that contains coupled differential equations. My main aim is to solve the mass balance in steady condition and feed the solution of steady state as initial guess for the dynamic simulation.
There are basically three state variables Ss,Xs and Xbh. The rate equations look like this:

> r1=µH(Ss/(Ks+Ss))(So/(Koh+So))Xbh+Kh(
>   (Xs⁄Xbh)/(Xs⁄Xbh+Kx))(So/(Koh+So))Xbh
>
> r2=(1-fp)bH*Xbh-Kh( (Xs⁄Xbh)/(Xs⁄Xbh+Kx))(So/(Koh+So))Xbh
>
> r3=µH(Ss/(Ks+Ss))(So/(Koh+So))Xbh-bH*Xbh

And the main differential equations derived from mole balance for CSTR are:

> dSs/dt = Q(Ss_in-Ss)+r1*V
>
> dXs/dt= Q(Xs_in-Xs)+r2*V
>
> dXbh/dt= Q(Xbh_in-Xbh)+r2*V

Here is my code till now:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
parameter=dict()
parameter['u_h']=6.0
parameter['k_oh']=0.20
parameter['k_s']=20.0
parameter['k_h']=3.0
parameter['k_x']=0.03
parameter['Y_h']=0.67
parameter['f_p']=0.08
parameter['b_h']=0.62 

Bulk_DO=2.0 #mg/L

#influent components:
infcomp=[56.53,182.9,16.625] #mgCOD/l

Q=684000 #L/hr
V=1040000 #l



def steady(z,*args):
    Ss=z[0]
    Xs=z[1]
    Xbh=z[2]
    def monod(My_S,My_K):
        return My_S/(My_S+My_K)

    #Conversion rates
    #Conversion of Ss
    r1=((-1/parameter['Y_h'])*parameter['u_h']*monod(Ss,parameter['k_s'])\
        +parameter['k_h']*monod(Xs/Xbh,parameter['k_x'])*monod(Bulk_DO,parameter['k_oh']))\
        *Xbh*monod(Bulk_DO,parameter['k_oh'])

    #Conversion of Xs
    r2=((1-parameter['f_p'])*parameter['b_h']-parameter['k_h']*monod(Xs/Xbh,parameter['k_x']))*Xbh

    #Conversion of Xbh
    r3=(parameter['u_h']*monod(Ss,parameter['k_s'])*monod(Bulk_DO,parameter['k_oh'])-parameter['b_h'])*Xbh

    f=np.zeros(3)
    f[0]=Q*(infcomp[0]-Ss)+r1*V
    f[1]=Q*(infcomp[1]-Xs)+r2*V
    f[2]=Q*(infcomp[2]-Xbh)+r3*V
    return f
initial_guess=(0.1,0.1,0.1)
soln=fsolve(steady,initial_guess,args=parameter)
print (soln)
```

How can I plot steady condition like this?
[steady state plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5or9.jpg)
The solution is also not what I want since the equations implies reduction in Ss and Xs and increase of Xbh values with time. Also one solution has negative value which is practically impossible.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you want to reproduce the plot you linked? Or do you only want to find possible values for Ss, Xs, Xbh such that the problem is at steady state?

Comment: Actually I want both. I want to show the time variation until the system reaches the steady state as shown in the link. And, I also want the steady state values to use them as an initial guess for dynamic simulation later on for which I will probably be using scipy.integrate.odeint

Comment: To figure out the time variation that that plot showed, you would already need to integrate these differential equations using scipy.integrate.odeint I think

Comment: @Ewoud, I only wanted the steady state values so that I could have a good initial guess for the odeint. What is a good initial guess? Does the initial guess refer to values of Ss,Xs and Xbh at t=0. Because if so, then they would be equal to my influent values (inf_comp).

Comment: But if you find the steady state values and use them as initial conditions for odeint, nothing should happen (since as they are steady state values)

Comment: What you are saying is very true. I am trying to find the steady state values with a constant influent data (given by inf_comp in the code), which is actually an average of hourly variations of influent components. However, for odeint I will use the time variation of influent as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution to getting negative values for your solution: instead of using fsolve, use least_squares, which allows you to set bounds to the possible values.

In the top, import:

```
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
```

And replace the fsolve statement with:

```
soln = least_squares(steady, initial_guess, bounds=[(0,0,0),(np.inf,np.inf,np.inf)], args=parameter)
```